# How do I make apps in Lego Mindstorms EV3 Education?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming

In the EV3 manual, it says you can create custom apps, in the same page as the IR control and Port View. How do you make a new app? I found a button under tools which says "Download as app", however this is pretty much the same as a usual project - is there a way to make apps special, or are they just the same?

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, the only real difference between an app and a project is which menu they appear in on the EV3.

Going a bit deeper though (and taking the title question literally), the LEGO "apps" that come pre-installed on the EV3 are not written using the LabView-based software. They are written in the LSMASM programming language, which is a language created specifically for the EV3. The source code for these can be found [here](https://github.com/ev3dev/lms2012-compat/tree/ev3dev-stretch/lmssrc).

You can modify these or create your own and compile them with the [lmsasm compiler](https://github.com/ev3dev/lmsasm) to create your own more advanced apps that can make use of all available EV3 bytecodes that allow you to do things you can't do in the other block programming languages.